# Discrete Function Approximation Error - Which type? (Applied math, signals)

Tags: approximation, signal-processing, approximation-theory, error-function

I have two functions, one derived via software, and we can call it the exact function, $f_{exact}$. The other is a result I got through hardware, and we can call it the approximation, $f_{approx}$.

Both functions are discrete, over 128 points, so it wouldn't make sense to try and derive an explicit expression.

Ok, so I want to calculate the "error" of the approximation, namely how different the approx function is from the exact function. What would be the best choice here to showcase the difference? I can calculate the maximum difference of the functions:

$$m = \max\limits_{i\in[0,127]}{f_{approx}(i)-f_{exact}(i)}$$

But I'm not sure if that's the best way to go. Any suggestions?

Comment: "best" depends on your needs.  A better choice for $m$ than the one you've written would probably be $m = \max_i \left|f_\text{approx}(i) - f_\text{exact}(i)\right|$ unless you know for sure that $f_\text{approx} \geq f_\text{exact}$.  This is essentially the $\ell^\infty$ norm on the space.  Some other norms are described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#.E2.84.93p_spaces).

Comment: @AntonioVargas you mean over $l^{128}$ space? or?

Comment: The $\infty$ is kind of just notation; it doesn't refer to the domain.  It's called that because of the fact that $$\lim_{p \to \infty} \|f\|_p = \|f\|_\infty$$ provided $f \in L_\infty$, where $$\|f\|_p = \left(\int |f|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}.$$  And I probably should have written $L_\infty$ instead of $\ell^\infty$ before.